# System function matches does not work in Oxygen schematron validation

Tags: xml, schematron, oxygenxml

I'm using OXygen XML Developer 15 to run a XML file validation against schematron. I'm getting errors on the system function "matches" on lines such as the following

```
     <assert test="matches(cda:languageCode/@code,'(([a-z]{2})(\-[A-Z]{2})?)')">
```

I searched for answers on the Internet and found [this posting](http://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/topic2540.html) indicating it's an oXygen issue. But, the posting was like 6 years ago. I can't believe the problem still exists. Or is there something I'm missing here.

Even though I really like oXygen, but I don't have to use it. So if I can not resolve this issue, can somebody recommend an alternative XML tool that can do schematron validation?

The following is the entirety of my schematron:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

    <schema xmlns="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" 
        xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3"
        queryBinding="xslt2">

    <title>cda4cdt</title>

    <ns prefix="cda" uri="urn:hl7-org:v3"/>

    <phase id='errors'>
        <active pattern='p-2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3-errors'/>
    </phase>

    <phase id='warning'>
        <active pattern='p-2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3-warning'/>
    </phase>

    <!-- errors -->

       <pattern id='p-2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3-errors' see='#p-2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3-errors' name='CDA for CDT - General Header Constraints - errors validation phase'
          queryBinding="xslt2">

        <rule context="/cda:ClinicalDocument">

        <assert test="(not(cda:realmCode/@code='US') and not(cda:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3')) or
              (cda:realmCode/@code='US' and cda:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3')">
        CONF-HP-15: In the case where IHE PCC enforces rule CONF-HP-15, the 
        ClinicalDocument/realmCode element SHALL be present.  It SHALL
        use the fixed value US.  If the US realm is not present, the template Id
        2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3 shall not be present.
        See the table describing the realm cases at: 
        http://wiki.ihe.net/index.php?title=1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1.1
        </assert>

        <assert test="cda:typeId[@extension='POCD_HD000040']">
        CONF-HP-16: The extension attribute of the typeId element SHALL be
        POCD_HD000040.
        </assert>

        <assert test="matches(cda:id/@root,'([0-2])(.([1-9][0-9]*|0))+') or matches(cda:id/@root,'([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})(\-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}){3}(\-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12})')">
        CONF-HP-17: The ClinicalDocument/id/@root attribute SHALL be a syntactically
        correct UUID or OID.
        CONF-HP-18: UUIDs SHALL be represented in the form
        XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX, where each X is a character from the set
        [A-Fa-f0-9].
        CONF-HP-19: OIDs SHALL be represented in dotted decimal notation, where each
        decimal number is either 0, or starts with a nonzero digit.  More formally,
        an OID SHALL be in the form ([0-2])(.([1-9][0-9]*|0))+.
        </assert>

        <assert test="not (cda:id[string-length(@root)>64])">
        CONF-HP-20: OIDs SHALL be no more than 64 characters in length.
        </assert>

        <assert test="cda:code">
        CONF-HP-21: The ClinicalDocument/code element SHALL be present and specifies the
        type of clincal document.
        </assert>

        <assert test="cda:title">
        CONF-HP-22: The title element SHALL be present and specifies the local name used
        for the document.
        </assert>


        <assert test="cda:effectiveTime">
        CONF-HP-23: The ClinicalDocument/effectiveTime element SHALL be present and
        specifies the creation time of the document.
        </assert>

        <assert test="cda:languageCode">
        CONF-HP-24: ClinicalDocument / languageCode element SHALL be present.
        </assert>

        <assert test="matches(cda:languageCode/@code,'(([a-z]{2})(\-[A-Z]{2})?)')">
        CONF-HP-25: ClincalDocument / languageCode SHALL be in the form nn, or nn-CC.
        </assert>

        <assert test="(not(cda:setId) and not(cda:versionNumber)) or (cda:setId and cda:versionNumber)">
        CONF-HP-28: Both ClinicalDocument/setId and ClinicalDocument/versionNumber SHALL
        be present or both SHALL be absent.
        </assert>

        <assert test="not((cda:setId/@extension = cda:id/@extension)
                          and (cda:setId/@root = cda:id/@root))">
        CONF-HP-29: The @extension and/or @root of ClinicalDocument/setId and
        ClinicalDocument/id SHALL be different when both are present.
        </assert>

        <assert test="not(cda:copyTime)">
        CONF-HP-30: A ClinicalDocument/copyTime element SHALL NOT be present.
        </assert>

        <assert test="cda:recordTarget/cda:patientRole">
        CONF-HP-31: At least one recordTarget/patientRole element SHALL be present.
        </assert>

        <assert test="string-length(cda:recordTarget/cda:patientRole/cda:patient/cda:birthTime/@value) >= 4 or cda:recordTarget/cda:patientRole/cda:patient/cda:birthTime/@nullFlavor">
        CONF-HP-32: A patient/birthTime element SHALL be present. The patient/birthTime
        element SHALL be precise at least to the year.  If unknown, it SHALL be
        represented using a flavor of null.
        </assert>

        <assert test="cda:recordTarget/cda:patientRole/cda:patient/cda:administrativeGenderCode[(@code and @codeSystem) or @nullFlavor]">
        CONF-HP-33: A patient/administrativeGenderCode element SHALL be present.
        If unknown, it SHALL be represented using a flavor of null.
        </assert>

        <assert test="cda:author/cda:time">
        CONF-HP-37: The author/time element SHALL be present.
        </assert>

        <assert test="cda:author/cda:assignedAuthor/cda:id">
        CONF-HP-38: The assignedAuthor/id element SHALL be present.
        </assert>

        <assert test="cda:author/cda:assignedAuthor/cda:assignedPerson or cda:author/cda:assignedAuthor/cda:assignedAuthoringDevice">
        CONF-HP-39: An assignedAuthor element SHALL contain at least one assignedPerson
        or assignedAuthoringDevice elements.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context='/cda:ClinicalDocument/cda:languageCode'>
        <assert test='
            (
            string-length(current()/@code) = 2
            and
            substring( current()/@code , 1, 2 ) = document("http://hit-testing.nist.gov:11080/muValidationCR/schematron/cda4cdt/languageCode.xml")/systems/system[@root="2.16.840.1.113883.6.121"]/code/@value
            )
            or
            (
            string-length(current()/@code) = 3
            and
            substring( current()/@code , 1, 3 ) = document("http://hit-testing.nist.gov:11080/muValidationCR/schematron/cda4cdt/languageCode.xml")/systems/system[@root="2.16.840.1.113883.6.121"]/code/@value
            )
            or
            (
            string-length(current()/@code) = 5
            and
            substring( current()/@code , 1, 2 ) = document("http://hit-testing.nist.gov:11080/muValidationCR/schematron/cda4cdt/languageCode.xml")/systems/system[@root="2.16.840.1.113883.6.121"]/code/@value
            and
            substring( current()/@code , 3, 1 ) = "-"
            and
            substring( current()/@code, 4, 2) = document("http://hit-testing.nist.gov:11080/muValidationCR/schematron/cda4cdt/languageCode.xml")/systems/system[@root="2.16.1"]/code/@value
            )
            or
            (
            string-length(current()/@code) = 6
            and
            substring( current()/@code , 1, 3 ) = document("http://hit-testing.nist.gov:11080/muValidationCR/schematron/cda4cdt/languageCode.xml")/systems/system[@root="2.16.840.1.113883.6.121"]/code/@value
            and
            substring( current()/@code , 4, 1 ) = "-"
            and
            substring( current()/@code, 5, 2) = document("http://hit-testing.nist.gov:11080/muValidationCR/schematron/cda4cdt/languageCode.xml")/systems/system[@root="2.16.1"]/code/@value
            )
            ' >
        CONF-HP-25, CONF-HP-26, CONF-HP-27: ClinicalDocument / languageCode SHALL be in the
        form nn, or nn-CC.  The nn portion of ClinicalDocument / languageCode SHALL be a
        legal ISO-639-1 language code in lowercase.  The CC portion ClinicalDocument /
        languageCode, if present, SHALL be an ISO-3166 country code in uppercase.
        </assert>

        </rule>

        <rule context="*[self::cda:patient or self::cda:guardianPerson or self::cda:assignedPerson or
                 self::cda:maintainingPerson or self::cda:relatedPerson or self::cda:associatedPerson]">
        <assert test="cda:name">
        CONF-HP-6: All patient guardianPerson, assignedPerson, maintainingPerson, relatedPerson,
        intendedRecipient/informationRecipient, associatedPerson, and relatedSubject/subject
        elements SHALL have a name.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context="*[self::cda:intendedRecipient/cda:informationRecipient or self::cda:relatedSubject/cda:subject]">
        <assert test="cda:informationRecipient/cda:name or cda:subject/cda:name">
        CONF-HP-6: All patient guardianPerson, assignedPerson, maintainingPerson, relatedPerson,
        intendedRecipient/informationRecipient, associatedPerson, and relatedSubject/subject
        elements SHALL have a name.
        </assert>
        </rule>   

        <rule context="*[self::cda:patientRole or self::cda:assignedAuthor or self::cda:assignedEntity[not(parent::cda:dataEnterer)] or self::cda:associatedEntity]">
        <assert test="cda:addr and cda:telecom">
        CONF-HP-7: All patientRole, assignedAuthor, assignedEntity[not(parent::dataEnterer)]
        and associatedEntity elements SHALL have an addr and telecom element.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context="*[self::cda:guardianOrganization or self::cda:providerOrganization or self::cda:wholeOrganization or self::cda:representedOrganization or self::cda:representedCustodianOrganization or self::cda:receivedOrganization or self::cda:scopingOrganization or self::cda:serviceProviderOrganization]">
        <assert test="cda:name and cda:addr and cda:telecom">
        CONF-HP-9: All guardianOrganization, providerOrganization, wholeOrganization, 
        representedOrganization, representedCustodianOrganization, receivedOrganization,
        scopingOrganization and serviceProviderOrganization elements SHALL have name, 
        addr and telecom elements.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context="*[self::cda:ClinicalDocument or self::cda:author or self::cda:dataEnterer or self::cda:encompassingEncounter]">
        <assert test="(cda:time/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/@value) >= 8) or
              (cda:time/cda:low/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:low/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:low/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:low/@value) >= 8) or
              (cda:time/cda:high/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:high/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:high/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:high/@value) >= 8) or
              (cda:time/cda:center/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:center/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:center/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:center/@value) >= 8) or
              (cda:time/cda:width/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:width/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:width/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:width/@value) >= 8)">
        CONF-HP-10: Times or time intervals found in the ClinicalDocument/effectiveTime,
        author/time, dataEnterer/time, legalAuthenticator/time, authenticator/time and
        encompassingEncounter/effectiveTime elements SHALL be precise to the day, and SHALL
        include a time zone if more precise than to the day.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context="*[self::cda:asOrganizationPartOf or self::cda:asMaintainedEntity or self::cda:relatedEntity or self::cda:serviceEvent or self::cda:serviceEvent/cda:performer or self::cda:encounterParticipant]">
        <assert test="
              (not(cda:time) or cda:time/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/@value) >= 4) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/@value) >= 4) or
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:low/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:low/@value) >= 4) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:high/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:high/@value) >= 4) or
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:center/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:center/@value) >= 4) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:width/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:width/@value) >= 4)">
        CONF-HP-11: Times or time intervals found in the asOrganizationPartOf/effectiveTime, 
        asMaintainedEntity/effectiveTime, relatedEntity/effectiveTime, serviceEvent/effectiveTime, 
        ClinicalDocument/participant/time, serviceEvent/performer/time and encounterParticipant/time 
        SHALL be precise at least to the year.
        </assert>
        </rule> 

        <rule context="/cda:ClinicalDocument/cda:participant/cda:time">
        <assert test="@nullFlavor or string-length(@value) >= 4">
        CONF-HP-11: Times or time intervals found in the asOrganizationPartOf/effectiveTime,
        asMaintainedEntity/effectiveTime, relatedEntity/effectiveTime, serviceEvent/effectiveTime,
        ClinicalDocument/participant/time, serviceEvent/performer/time and encounterParticipant/time
        SHALL be precise at least to the year.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context="//*[self::cda:addr/@nullFlavor or self::cda:name/@nullFlavor or self::cda:telecom/@nullFlavor]">
        <assert test="document('http://hit-testing.nist.gov:11080/muValidationCR/schematron/cda4cdt/voc.xml')/systems/system[@group='Null Flavors']/code[@value = current()/@nullFlavor]">
        CONF-HP-9: When name, addr, telecom information is unknown and where these elements 
        are required to be present, the fact that the information is unknown SHALL be represented 
        using an appropriate value for the nullFlavor attribute on the element.  Legal values 
        according to this specification come from the HL7 NullFlavor vocabulary. 
        </assert>
        </rule> 

        <rule context="//*[self::cda:telecom]">
        <assert test="not(starts-with(@value,'tel:')) or matches(@value,'tel:\+?[-0-9().]+')">
        CONF-HP-12: Telephone numbers SHALL match the regular expression pattern tel:\+?[-0-9().]+ 
        </assert>
        <assert test="not(starts-with(@value,'tel:')) or matches(@value,'.\d+.' )">
        CONF-HP-13: At least one dialing digit SHALL be present in the phone number after visual 
        separators are removed.
        </assert>
        </rule> 

        <rule context="*[self::cda:telecom]">
        <assert test="@value or @nullFlavor">
        CONF-HP-14: If the telephone number is unknown it SHALL be represented using the appopriate
        flavor of null.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context="*[self::cda:assignedEntity[parent::cda:dataEnterer]]">
        <assert test="cda:assignedPerson">
        CONF-HP-40: When dataEnterer is present, an assignedEntity/assignedPerson element SHALL
        be present.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context="cda:informant">
        <assert test="not(cda:relatedEntity) or cda:relatedEntity[@classCode='CON' or @classCode='PRS' or @classCode='CAREGIVER' or @classCode='AGNT' or @classCode='PROV']">
        CONF-HP-45: Allowable values for informant/relatedEntity/@classCode SHALL be CON, PRS,
        CAREGIVER, AGNT or PROV from the RoleClass vocabulary.
        </assert>

        <assert test="cda:assignedEntity/cda:assignedPerson or cda:relatedEntity/cda:relatedPerson">
        CONF-HP-43: When informant is present, an assignedEntity/assignedPerson or 
        relatedEntity/relatedPerson element SHALL be present.
        </assert>

        <assert test="not(cda:relatedEntity/@classCode='PRS') or document('http://hit-testing.nist.gov:11080/muValidationCR/schematron/cda4cdt/voc.xml')/systems/system[@codeSystemName='LOINC'][@group='Personal Relationship Role Type']/code[@value = current()/cda:relatedEntity/cda:code/@code] or current()/cda:code/@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96'">
        CONF-HP-46: When relatedEntity/@classCode is PRS, values in relatedEntity/code SHALL come
        from the HL7 PersonalRelationshipRoleType vocabulary or from SNOMED, any subtype ofâ€œ
        Person in the familyâ€ (303071001).
        </assert>            
        </rule>

        <rule context="cda:informationRecipient/cda:intendedRecipient">
        <assert test="cda:informationRecipient or cda:receivedOrganization">
        CONF-HP-50: When informationRecipient is used, at least one 
        informationRecipient/intendedRecipient/informationRecipient or 
        informationRecipient/intendedRecipient/receivedOrganization SHALL be present.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context="*[self::cda:legalAuthenticator]">
        <assert test="(cda:time/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/@value) >= 8) or
              (cda:time/cda:low/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:low/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:low/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:low/@value) >= 8) or
              (cda:time/cda:high/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:high/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:high/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:high/@value) >= 8) or
              (cda:time/cda:center/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:center/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:center/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:center/@value) >= 8) or
              (cda:time/cda:width/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:width/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:width/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:width/@value) >= 8)">
        CONF-HP-10: Times or time intervals found in the ClinicalDocument/effectiveTime,
        author/time, dataEnterer/time, legalAuthenticator/time, authenticator/time and
        encompassingEncounter/effectiveTime elements SHALL be precise to the day, and SHALL
        include a time zone if more precise than to the day.
        </assert>

        <assert test="cda:assignedEntity/cda:assignedPerson">
        CONF-HP-51: The assignedEntity/assignedPerson element SHALL be present 
        in legalAuthenticator.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context="*[self::cda:authenticator]">
        <assert test="(cda:time/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/@value) >= 8) or
              (cda:time/cda:low/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:low/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:low/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:low/@value) >= 8) or
              (cda:time/cda:high/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:high/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:high/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:high/@value) >= 8) or
              (cda:time/cda:center/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:center/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:center/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:center/@value) >= 8) or
              (cda:time/cda:width/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:width/@value) >= 8) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:width/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:width/@value) >= 8)">
        CONF-HP-10: Times or time intervals found in the ClinicalDocument/effectiveTime,
        author/time, dataEnterer/time, legalAuthenticator/time, authenticator/time and
        encompassingEncounter/effectiveTime elements SHALL be precise to the day, and SHALL
        include a time zone if more precise than to the day.
        </assert>

        <assert test="cda:assignedEntity/cda:assignedPerson">
        CONF-HP-52: The assignedEntity/assignedPerson element SHALL be present
        in an authenticator element.
        </assert>
        </rule>

    </pattern>

    <!-- warning -->

       <pattern id='p-2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3-warning' see='#p-2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3-warning' name='CDA for common document type - warning validation phase'>

        <rule context="*[self::cda:guardian or self::cda:assignedEntity[parent::cda:dataEnterer] or self::cda:relatedEntity or self::cda:intendedRecipient or self::cda:relatedSubject or self::cda:participantRole]">
        <assert test="cda:addr and cda:telecom">
        CONF-HP-8: All guardian, dataEnterer/assignedEntity, relatedEntity, intendedRecipient,
        relatedSubject and participantRole elements SHOULD have an addr and telecom element.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context="*[self::cda:ClinicalDocument or self::cda:author or self::cda:dataEnterer or self::cda:legalAuthenticator or self::cda:authenticator or self::cda:encompassingEncounter]">
        <assert test="(cda:time/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/@value) >= 14) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/@value) >= 14) or
              (cda:time/cda:low/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:low/@value) >= 14) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:low/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:low/@value) >= 14) or
              (cda:time/cda:high/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:high/@value) >= 14) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:high/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:high/@value) >= 14) or
              (cda:time/cda:center/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:center/@value) >= 14) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:center/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:center/@value) >= 14) or
              (cda:time/cda:width/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:time/cda:width/@value) >= 14) or 
              (cda:effectiveTime/cda:width/@nullFlavor or string-length(cda:effectiveTime/cda:width/@value) >= 14)">
        CONF-HP-10: Times or time intervals found in the ClinicalDocument/effectiveTime,
        author/time, dataEnterer/time, legalAuthenticator/time, authenticator/time and
        encompassingEncounter/effectiveTime elements SHOULD be precise to the second. 
        </assert>
        </rule>


        <!-- these high and low should be precise to the day -->
        <rule context="*[self::cda:high[ancestor::cda:effectiveTime[parent::cda:asOrganizationPartOf]] or self::cda:high[ancestor::cda:effectiveTime[parent::cda:asMaintainedEntity]] or self::cda:high[ancestor::cda:effectiveTime[parent::cda:relatedEntity]] or self::cda:high[ancestor::cda:effectiveTime[parent::cda:serviceEvent]] or self::cda:high[ancestor::cda:time[parent::cda:encounterParticipant]]]">
        <assert test="@nullFlavor or string-length(@value) >= 8">
        CONF-HP-11: Times or time intervals found in the asOrganizationPartOf/effectiveTime, 
        asMaintainedEntity/effectiveTime, relatedEntity/effectiveTime, 
        ClinicalDocument/participant/time, serviceEvent/effectiveTime, serviceEvent/performer/time
        and encounterParticipant/time ... SHOULD be precise to the day.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context="*[self::cda:low[ancestor::cda:effectiveTime[parent::cda:asOrganizationPartOf]] or self::cda:low[ancestor::cda:effectiveTime[parent::cda:asMaintainedEntity]] or self::cda:low[ancestor::cda:effectiveTime[parent::cda:relatedEntity]] or self::cda:low[ancestor::cda:effectiveTime[parent::cda:serviceEvent]] or self::cda:low[ancestor::cda:time[parent::cda:encounterParticipant]]]">
        <assert test="@nullFlavor or string-length(@value) >= 8">
        CONF-HP-11: Times or time intervals found in the asOrganizationPartOf/effectiveTime, 
        asMaintainedEntity/effectiveTime, relatedEntity/effectiveTime, 
        ClinicalDocument/participant/time, serviceEvent/effectiveTime, serviceEvent/performer/time 
        and encounterParticipant/time ... SHOULD be precise to the day.
        </assert>
        </rule> 


        <rule context="/cda:ClinicalDocument/cda:participant/cda:time">
        <assert test="@nullFlavor or string-length(@value) >= 8">
        CONF-HP-11: Times or time intervals found in the asOrganizationPartOf/effectiveTime,
        asMaintainedEntity/effectiveTime, relatedEntity/effectiveTime,
        ClinicalDocument/participant/time, serviceEvent/effectiveTime, serviceEvent/performer/time
        and encounterParticipant/time ... SHOULD be precise to the day.
        </assert>
        </rule>

        <rule context="cda:patient">
        <assert test="string-length(cda:birthTime/@value) >= 8">
        CONF-HP-32: The patient/birthTime element SHOULD be precise at least to the day.
        </assert>

        <assert test="document('http://hit-testing.nist.gov:11080/muValidationCR/schematron/cda4cdt/voc.xml')/systems/system[@codeSystemName='LOINC'][@group='Administrative Gender']/code[@value = current()/cda:administrativeGenderCode/@code]">
        CONF-HP-33: Administrative Gender codes used to describe the gender of the patient
        SHOULD come from the HL7 AdministrativeGender vocabulary. The OID for this 
        vocabulary domain is 2.16.840.1.113883.5.1.
        </assert>

        <assert test="not(current()/cda:maritalStatusCode) or document('http://hit-testing.nist.gov:11080/muValidationCR/schematron/cda4cdt/voc.xml')/systems/system[@codeSystemName='LOINC'][@group='Marital Status']/code[@value = current()/cda:maritalStatusCode/@code]">
        CONF-HP-34: Marital status codes used to describe the marital status of the patient 
        SHOULD come from the HL7 MaritalStatus vocabulary. The OID for this vocabulary 
        domain is 2.16.840.1.113883.5.2.
        </assert>
        </rule>      

    </pattern>


    <!-- notes -->

       <pattern id='p-2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3-note' see='#p-2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3-note' name='CDA for common document type - note validation phase'>
        <rule context="/cda:ClinicalDocument">
           <assert test='cda:templateId[@root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.10"]'>
              CONF-HP-3: To indicate conformance to Level 1 (which also asserts compliance with
              all general or non-level-specific constraints), ClinicalDocument/templateId elements
              MAY be present with the value shown: &lt;templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.10'/&gt;
           </assert>
           <assert test='cda:templateId[@root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.20"]'>
              CONF-HP-4: To indicate conformance to Level 2 (which also asserts compliance with
              all general or non-level-specific constraints), ClinicalDocument/templateId elements
              MAY be present with the value shown: &lt;templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.20'/&gt;
           </assert>
           <assert test='cda:templateId[@root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.30"]'>
              CONF-HP-5: To indicate conformance to Level 3 (which also asserts compliance with
              all general or non-level-specific constraints), ClinicalDocument/templateId elements
              MAY be present with the value shown: &lt;templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.30'/&gt;
           </assert>
           <assert test='cda:informant'>
              CONF-HP-42: The informant element MAY be present.
           </assert>

        </rule>
        <rule context="cda:patientRole">
           <assert test='cda:providerOrganization'>
              CONF-HP-36: The providerOrganization element MAY be present.
           </assert>
        </rule>
        <rule context="cda:dataEnterer">
           <assert test="cda:time">
             CONF-HP-41: The time element MAY be present. If present, it represents the starting
             time of entry of the data.
           </assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>

    </schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `matches` function is not available in XPath 1.0 which will be used by default for your Schematron file, it is defined in XPath 2.0, see
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches

If you use ISO Schematron you just need to set `queryBinding="xslt2"` on the root element and then XPath 2.0 functions will be recognized automatically.

Regards,
George

Comment: I do have the queryBinding="xslt2" on the root element but still having the errors. Please see the entire schematron I have just added to the original posting.

Comment: Yes, but that is not an ISO Schematron schema. Pre-ISO Schematron did not have a way to specify the XPath version inside the schema, so this should be specified as an application option. In oXygen you have this under "Options->Preferences -- XML / XML Parser / Schematron -- Schematron XPath version" and you need to select "2.0" instead of "1.0" as its value. Make sure you remove the two queryBinding attributes that you added.

Comment: Another option is to change your schema to be ISO Schematron. To do that change the namespace of the schema from xmlns="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" to xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron", replace the "name" attributes on the "pattern" element with a "title" element as the first child of each "pattern" element and remove the "queryBinding" attribute from the "pattern" element but keep the one from the "schema" element.